How to expand yas-snippets in eshell (under Doom)
(This may have nothing to do with Doom-emacs, but because I use it, I should mention it)
The famous "for-loop" expansion (https://xenodium.com/yasnippet-in-emacs-eshell/) does not work for me.
When I hit type "for", then TAB, I was hoping to see for f in * { echo "$f";
But what really appears is a set of command matches to those starting with "for".
Hitting SPC just enters a space.
How do I trigger the snippet in eshell?
(Yes, I know I can type for then M-x yas-expand, which works as expected.
I was hoping for something more elegant.)
